# Parse list of complex JSON objects using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a list of JSON objects something like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "A",
    "objs": [
      { "obj1": 1 },
      { "obj2": 0 },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "A",
    "objs": [
      { "obj1": 1 },
      { "obj2": 0 },
    ]
  }
]
```

And would like to load them into a list of MyObj:

```
class MyObj {
  private final String id;
  private final HashMap<String, Integer> objs;

  // Constructors, etc. here...
}

ArrayList<MyObj> list;
```

Is there any smart way to do this using the Jackson ObjectMapper or other bindings; i.e., with minimal boilerplate code? Without the HashMap it would be a simple matter of:

```
list = mapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<ArrayList<MyOBJ>>() {});
```

But the HashMap pretty much seems to kill that. Ideas?

Comment: A JSON array cannot be mapped (by default) to a `Map`. You'll need a custom deserializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need a model class for your JSON. Then you should to write your own parser for reading data to array (Map, List, etc.). Jackson.

Small example from my old project.

Model class:

```
package ru.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Entry implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionID = 8201337883209943936L;

    private Integer primary_id;
    private Integer id;
    private String description;
    private Integer votes;
    private String author;
    private Date date;
    private String gifURL;
    private String previewURL;
    private String embedId;
    private String type;

//  getters and setters
}
```

Example of parser:

```
public static List<Entry> getAllEntries(String jsonString) {        
    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();                               
        try {
            if (jsonString.length() == 0) {
                throw new Exception("Empty json!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonString);
            JsonNode resultNode = rootNode.findPath("result"); // choose concrete element in JSON array
            if (resultNode.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < resultNode.size(); i++) {
                    entries.add(objectMapper.readValue(resultNode.get(i).toString(), Entry.class));
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return entries;
}
```

Example of JSON:

```
{"result":
[
{"id":94,
"description":"description111",
"votes":1,
"author":"sashvd",
"date":"Mar 15, 2013 4:09:03 PM",
"gifURL":"http://-..",
"previewURL":"http://.."}
],
"totalCount":88}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use Jackson-annotations, and don't care that much about performance, you can do this nasty little trick :

```
// Put this in the MyObj class
@JsonSetter(value="objs")
public void setObjs(HashMap<String, Integer>[] units) {
    objs = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (HashMap<String, Integer> unit : units) {
        for (String key : unit.keySet())
            objs.put(key, unit.get(key));
    }
}
```

But the clean way would be to write a `MyObjDeserializer`, as suggested by @Sotirios.

Watch out for those leading commas inside the `"objs"` arrays.